# Suddenly receiving the below error in Android Studio. The app was working fine then when I re-opened it I got this error. Anyone know why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk:AdBuddiz-Java:3.+.
>        Required by:
>            MaleAdvise:app:unspecified
>   Could not resolve com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk:AdBuddiz-Java:3.+.
>   Failed to list versions for com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk:AdBuddiz-Java.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/purplebrain/adbuddiz/sdk/AdBuddiz-Java/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/purplebrain/adbuddiz/sdk/AdBuddiz-Java/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com
>   Could not resolve com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk:AdBuddiz-Java:3.+.
>   Failed to list versions for com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk:AdBuddiz-Java.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/purplebrain/adbuddiz/sdk/AdBuddiz-Java/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/purplebrain/adbuddiz/sdk/AdBuddiz-Java/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   repo1.maven.org
>   Could not resolve com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk:AdBuddiz-Java:3.+.
>   Failed to list versions for com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk:AdBuddiz-Java.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repository.adbuddiz.com/maven/com/purplebrain/adbuddiz/sdk/AdBuddiz-Java/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not GET 'http://repository.adbuddiz.com/maven/com/purplebrain/adbuddiz/sdk/AdBuddiz-Java/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   repository.adbuddiz.com
>   Could not resolve com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk:AdBuddiz-Java:3.+.
>   Failed to list versions for com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk:AdBuddiz-Java.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/purplebrain/adbuddiz/sdk/AdBuddiz-Java/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/purplebrain/adbuddiz/sdk/AdBuddiz-Java/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   repo1.maven.org

Comment: Not sure, but maybe the library that you are using, isn't reachable thru gradle anymore?

Comment: That's what I am thinking, but why? And how do I get it back?

Comment: Not sure how are you importing the library, which dependecies does it have... I would contact the guys at AdBuddiz and ask them what is up.

Comment: OK thanks... will try

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I changes the reference from : compile 'com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk:AdBuddiz-Java:3.+'

To this specific version : compile 'com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk:AdBuddiz-Java:3.0.18'

Problem solved!